# How to remove the word and digit with underscore in a string

Tags: regex

I would like to use regular expressions to remove the "2_abc_" in the following string:

`$a="2_abc_300_300_300_300_1_120";`

I have tried:

`$a=~ s/^\d_\w*//;`

but it doesn't work since `w` includes numeric, undercore and alphabet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[A-Za-z]` insted of `\w`. Or just `[a-z]` if you want just lower case letters.

Also, if you want at least one letter use `+` instead of `*`.

If you want exactly 3 letters use something like `[a-z]{3}`.

Comment: $a=~s/^\d_[a-z]+_//;

Thanks for your answer, it works !

Answer (score 1):

What about `$a~=s/$\d+_[A-Za-z]+_(.*)//;`